# Convert Generic Dictionary to different type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections

Is there a quick way to convert a Generic Dictionary from one type to another

I have this

```
IDictionary<string, string> _commands;
```

and need to pass it to a function that takes a slightly different typed Dictionary

```
public void Handle(IDictionary<string, Object> _commands);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I suppose I would write

```
Handle(_commands.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => (object)p.Value));
```

Not the most efficient thing in the world to do, but until covariance is in, that's the breaks.

Comment: The ToDictionary method requires 'using System.Linq;' (I was scratching my head for a minute or two).

Answer (score 1):

maybe this function can be useful for you

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> Convert(IDictionary<string, string> dic) {
    foreach(var item in dic) {
        yield return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}
```

And you will call it like so:

```
Handle(Convert(_commands));
```

Answer (score 1):

could something like this do?

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

dict.Add(1, "One");
dict.Add(2, "Two");
dict.Add(3, "Three");
dict.Add(4, "Four");
dict.Add(5, "Five");

object dictObj = (object)dict;

IDictionary temp = (IDictionary)dictObj;

Dictionary<int, object> objs = new Dictionary<int, object>();

foreach (DictionaryEntry de in temp)
{
    objs.Add((int)de.Key, (object)de.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use

```
Dim myDictionary AS New Dictionary(Of Object, Object)
```

This would then be able to accept any types

Comment: No, it won't work, because a Dictionary<object,object> isn't a IDictionary<string,object>...