# Convert IDictionary to Dictionary

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I have to convert `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, decimal>` to `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, decimal>`, and i can't. I tried the ToDictionary method and can't specify right arguments.

I've tried the following:

```
// my dictionary is PlannedSurfaces (of type IDictionary<string, decimal>)
blabla.ToDictionary<string, decimal>(localConstruction.PlannedSurfaces)
```

Comment: post your code, and any errors...

Comment: blabla.ToDictionary<string, decimal>(localConstruction.PlannedSurfaces)
IDictionary<string, decimal> PlannedSurfaces, this is my dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Generic Dictionary to different type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702588/convert-generic-dictionary-to-different-type)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`var newDict = new Dictionary<string, decimal>(oldDictionary)`

Answer (score 33):

or in linq

```
var castedDico = dictionary.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var newDictionary = (IDictionary<string, boolean>)ex.Data;
```

`IDictionary` can be casted as a `Dictionary`.

Note that if dictionary is empty/null, it will throw exception.

Answer (score -2):

```cs
IDictionary dictionary = GetDictionary();
var typedDictionary = new Dictionary<object, object>();
foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys)
{
    typedDictionary[key] = dictionary[key];
}
```