# Error: Can't convert from Dictionary to IDictionary

Tags: dictionary, idictionary

Why is there an error 
Error   52  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary>'

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> tempResultIDList = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
test(tempResultIDList);

public bool test(IDictionary<string,IList<string>> a)
  {
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Generic Dictionary to different type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702588/convert-generic-dictionary-to-different-type)

Answer (score 2):

`Dictionary<string, List<string>>` implements `IDictionary<string, List<string>>`, while you're trying to cast it to `IDictionary<string, *I*List<string>>`. It is not allowed, because `IDictionary<string, IList<string>>` has e.g. the method `Add` accepting instance of `IList<string>`, while `Add` method in your `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` won't accept `IList<string>` as its input.