# What is wrong with this return from an async function

Tags: .net, vb.net, function, asynchronous, return

Here is the relevant code:

```
Protected Async Function GetMonthlyBillsAsync(month As Date) As Task(Of IDictionary(Of String, Lazy(Of iBill)))
    Dim invoiceNumbers = New Dictionary(Of String, Lazy(Of PlumbersSuppliesCoOpBill))
'Stuff to fill the dictionary which works giving 66 elements
    Return invoiceNumbers
End Function
```

Called from:

```
Dim thisMonth = Await GetMonthlyBillsAsync(sd)
```

When the return statement executes I get a *NullReferenceException* with:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled

  HResult=-2147467261

  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

  Source=ConsoleApplication1

  StackTrace:

   at ConsoleApplication1.Module1.Main() in \\fileserver\data\Users\Dale\Visual Studio Projects\SupplierBills\ConsoleApplication1\Module1.vb:line 7

   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)

   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()

   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)

   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

  InnerException:
```

What is going on?

Comment: Are you saying your logic works without the async/await keywords?

Comment: good question - I'll check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the return type as below :
Task(Of IDictionary(Of String, Lazy(**Of iBill**)))

But you return type of function is  :
Dictionary(Of String, Lazy(Of **PlumbersSuppliesCoOpBill**))

You can clearly see the type is different so that is why it is breaking.

Match up the returning type with your declared type would solve your problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, the answer is I wasn't paying attention and was catching the wrong exception.

The correct exception was:

> Unable to cast Dictionary(Of String, Lazy(Of PlumbersSuppliesCoOpBill)) to iDictionary(Of String, Lazy(Of iBill))

which makes perfect sense as is explained in [Error: Can't convert from Dictionary to IDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334977/error-cant-convert-from-dictionary-to-idictionary) - its not the Dictionary to iDictionary that's the problem - its the PlumbersSuppliesCoOpBill to iBill within the dictionary.

I changed the type of the return value to Dictionary(Of String, Lazy(Of iBill)) and it works.