# Get IDictionary(of String, IDictionary(of String, String)) using Linq

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a function that expects to receive as an argument the type
IDictionary(of String, IDictionary(of String, String)).

I want to build my dictionaries using Linq:

```
Dim dic = myCol.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Key1,
                             Function(x) x.children.ToDictionary(Function(x2) x2.Key2,
                                                                 Function(x2) x2.name)
```

But when I the send dic to MyFunc, I get the error:

```
Unable to cast object of type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]]
```

As far as I understand, this is because `IDictionary(of String, IDictionary of String, String))` does not implement `IDictionary(of String, Dictionary(of String, String))` (as explained by @penartur in [his post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334977/error-cant-convert-from-dictionary-to-idictionary)).

This being said, how can I achieve this using Linq?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but you could try:

```
Dim dic = myCol.ToDictionary(
    Function(x) x.Key1,
    Function(x) DirectCast(
        x.children.ToDictionary(Function(x2) x2.Key2,
                                Function(x2) x2.name),
        IDictionary(Of String, String)))
```

Comment: Yes, it works. That was exactly what I was testing while you wrote the answer! ;) Thank you!